# How to make an Excel formula reference cell on the same row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm doing a sheet for scores in a rhythm game, and I want to make it show percentages. The A row is the name of the song, the B row is my score and C row is my highest score, on D it will show the percentage. How do I make it reference the B and C column on the same row? Instead of writing `"=B1/C1*100"` for row 1, `"=B2/C2*100"` for row 2 and so on and so forth, I want to have a formula I can simply copy in the entire row instead of needing to change the number for everything. I've tried for over an hour to find a solution online but I can't.
Edit: Since I used the * symbol it made it italic so I fixed that

Comment: If you write `=B1/C1*100` in row 1 and drag down, the `1` will change to `2`, `3`, `4` etc as you drag. Perhaps you are over-thinking here.

Comment: In excel if you type `=B1/C1*100` in `D1` dragging the formula down to `D2`, `D3`, etc. will automatically change the ranges as desired. You can also copy and paste the formula cell to the range you want it to be and Excel will adapt the ranges. (If you would use `=B$1/C$1*100` it would *not* change the row numbers.)

Comment: @P.b Somebody did say that to me a while ago and I tried it and it didn't work, but when I read just know what you said I realized what I was doing wrong, I was copying the text of the formula, going into another cell and pasting it there, but now I realized that I'm supposed to copy the cell, and not the text, and paste it to another cell. So thanks for helping me out.